imaplib.IMAP4.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED, unable to access any folder apart from inbox
I am unable to access any other folder apart from the inbox using imaplib. Did try changing the names of the folders to [Gmail]/Drafts but still the same error. The IMAP error: SELECT command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command'] error and command CLOSE illegal in state AUTH

Please provide some code.  We can’t debug a terse overview.

You send a SEARCH command before the authentication was successfully completed. That's pretty much all that can be said with this few information.
